# laravel $foreach получить только уникальные назначенные

Tags: php, laravel

```
  @foreach($post as $ganre)

  {{$ganre->genre}}

  @endforeach
```

Comment: через `@foreach( array_unique($post) as $ganre)` можно попробовать. Или же хранить значние как ключ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На вскидку, если вам нужно только уникальные жанры вывести -

```
@foreach($post->pluck('genre')->unique() as $genre)

    {{$genre}}

@endforeach
```

Comment: огромное спасибо